# Separate one data column into two

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am currently working with a .txt file that looks like this. (there is a space in front of the first bracket)

```
| Column 0 |
| 01/01/2013 | 123.56 |
| 02/12/2013 | 25.34 |
```

The data is coming into SQL Server into one column. I tried to set the delimiter to a "bar" but it still will not split the column. I assume there is a space in the front of the bar so it is not recognizing it.

I need to separate this column into 2 separate columns one for "Date" the other for "Total". Using SSIS, what would be the best way to do this? I need SSIS as I will be doing some other transforms on this data once it is separated.

Comment: By "bracket", you mean pipe? And to ensure I understand the nuances, the delimiter has a space padding on either side thus ` | MyDate | SomeValue | `

Comment: Apologies, Yes, the delimiter is the Pipe. And I believe you are correct, there is a space padding on either side.

Comment: Search & Replace `|` with `,`.  Save as `.csv`  Open in spreadsheet (Excel).  Save the 2 columns you want as `.csv`.  I assume SSIS can handle `.csv` files.

Comment: @DavidStarkey. Sorry, I should have been more descriptive. This needs to be an automated process. We have an SAP system that drops the file into a folder. The Department using this data does not want to touch it. I need to import it into an SSIS package so that I can transform the data for some reports. This job will run daily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way would be to use a **derived column** transformation. You can use

> SUBSTRING( «character_expression», «start», «length» )

If the length of your columns is static. An example for your date would be:

> SUBSTRING( INPUTColumn, 3(character count where column begins), 10(size of column))

If the size of your columns varies then I would use a *scrip task* to split the strings and format the information yourself. I can provide some sample code if you need it.

**EDIT:** I looked again at your sample, at this point I'm assuming your cloumn size is dynamic. If so, the best way will be to use a scrip task. You can then split the lines into an array with .split() if you add the "|" and " " and arguments to split they will be removed from the original string. you can then format your data and output it to you database.

The first step is to create a string parameter within ssis. Its value should be your file path. Then ad a **Source** Script task to your dataflow. In the editor under custom properies add that parameter to *readOnlyVariables*

Then open the file like this :

```
    byte[] empty = new byte[] { };
    //Outside parameter for the ssisparameter file path
    //Check for the parameter existance
    IDTSVariable100 filePathVariable;
    try
    {
        filePathVariable = this.ReadOnlyVariables["ParameterName"];
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {

    }
    string filePath = filePathVariable.Value.ToString();
```

This will split your file into an array of lines.

```
 private String[] fileLines;
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            //Read file and split into lines
            string fileStream = reader.ReadToEnd();
            fileLines = fileStream.Split('\n');
        }
```

Create an array like this with all the delimiters you want to use.

```
 private char[] delimiters = { ' ', ':', '\n', '\\', '=' };
```

Then loop through you lines using something like this:

```
string[] Tokens = fileLines[index].Split(delimiters);
```

All of the above should be included in your preExecute section of the script task. The idea here is to separate all your infomation into separate lists which will represent columns(so a list for dates and a list for values).

In your *scrip task editor* you can add the columns as outputs.
and then add this to the output section of the script:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
    {
        outputBuffer.AddRow();
        outputBuffer.date = dateList[i];
        outputBuffer.value = valueList[i];
     }
```

Comment: Yes, please. I would like to see some Examples. The Script Task is a little new to me, still learning. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for all of this. I am not familiar with the Script Task so this may take me a little to absorb. My HR department changed the data/info criteria shortly after you finished this so I will have to see if it will still work. I made another post with more information on the new criteria. Thank you again.

Comment: I looked at your other post. If you want to write an automated import for a file of that complexity it's gonna be hard to avoid the script task. The "derived column" may be able to help you but you would still need to hard code the conditional statements in it. If you need some more help with the scrip let me know.